# Create a new div class row every 3 items fetch from SQL with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I am trying to create a gallery.. Every 3 images I need to create a new div and start again.(trying to turn this html to php-sql)
[image]

I am trying that with this php code

```
<?php
  //get images from database
  $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id");

   if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $imagethumb = 'images/thumb/'.$row["file_name"];
    $imagefront = 'images/'.$row["file_name"];

    $i = 0;

    if($i++ % 3 == 0){
    ?>
    <div class=" bd-layoutcontainer bd-columns bd-no-margins">
       <div class="bd-container-inner">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">                             
                   <div class="bd-columnwrapper-136 <?php  
                       list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imagethumb);                                
                       if($width > 298){
                          echo 'col-sm-6';
                       }else{
                          echo 'col-sm-3';
                     }
                   ?>">
                   <?php echo '<div class="bd-layoutcolumn-136 bd-column">
                               <div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
                               <div class="bd-hoverbox-6 bd-effect-fade">
                               <div class="bd-slidesWrapper">' ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $imagethumb; ?>" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
                         <img src="<?php echo $imagefront; ?>" alt="" />
                        </a>
                  <?php echo '
                              </div>
                              </div> 
                              </div>
                              </div>'
                  ?> 
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   <?php
      }
      }
      } 
?>
```

I am using the if statement $i % 3 == 0 to create a new div but i get every image one down of other and not three images in row like the pic..[image]
 This is what i get

What else should i do?

I need every 3 imgs to create the

```
     <div class=" bd-layoutcontainer bd-columns bd-no-margins">
       ..............
     </div>
```

And div never multiplied by 3 i just got one div back

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're getting instead? If I can't help, others may be able to.

Comment: show your css. try use float:left for bd-layoutcontainer class. since i don't see your styles i can't exactly tell if it works.

Comment: @AMH i have the same css... I created that gallery with html and trying to turn it to php.. So its not about css

Comment: Side note: If that's your full code, you have a missing closing div for `<div class=" bd-layoutcontainer bd-columns bd-no-margins">`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i just updated my question thank you

Comment: also the bracing for `if($width > 298){` doesn't match your `else`, so you have a few issues here. Matter of fact, your bracing is off entirely and php's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php should be throwing you parse errors. Starting from `if($query->num_rows > 0){` and for a few others.

Comment: I won't be able to fix your code since nested bracing isn't my forté, sorry.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no worries thanks for your time#

Comment: You're welcome Maria. If you're not using a code editor with pair matching (bracing etc.), it would help you greatly if you did. I myself use Notepad++ https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ but there are a few other (free) ones that are just as good.

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE and it generates the bracing by itself

Comment: it's good practice to use three equals signs when checking for equality and use brackets to make things clearer and ensure that the precedence is how you intend it to be: `(($i++ % 3) === 0)

Comment: You have a different number of opening div tags to your closing div tags also

Answer (score 0):

```
</div>
<div class=" bd-layoutcontainer bd-columns bd-no-margins">
```

i think  if statement $i % 3 == 0 you should add close tag and create a new div.Hope to solve your issue.

Comment: That would mean that there would need an opening div above that, which isn't in their posted code.

Comment: There's more to this. You should put their code in an (code) editor.

Comment: Yes . i mean first opening and closing div outside "if statement $i % 3==0 " and inside add closing div and add opening div if not end loop.

Answer (score 0):

define  $i = 0; before while loop

```
<?php
  //get images from database
  $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id");

   if($query->num_rows > 0){
$i=0;
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
$imagethumb = 'images/thumb/'.$row["file_name"];
$imagefront = 'images/'.$row["file_name"];

if($i++ % 3 == 0){
?>
<div class=" bd-layoutcontainer bd-columns bd-no-margins">
   <div class="bd-container-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">                             
               <div class="bd-columnwrapper-136 <?php  
                   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imagethumb);                                
                   if($width > 298){
                      echo 'col-sm-6';
                   }else{
                      echo 'col-sm-3';
                 }
               ?>">
               <?php echo '<div class="bd-layoutcolumn-136 bd-column">
                           <div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
                           <div class="bd-hoverbox-6 bd-effect-fade">
                           <div class="bd-slidesWrapper">' ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $imagethumb; ?>" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
                     <img src="<?php echo $imagefront; ?>" alt="" />
                    </a>
              <?php echo '
                          </div>
                          </div> 
                          </div>
                          </div>'
              ?> 
              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   <?php
  }
  }
  } 
?>
```